# Looping with Delay in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I loop the below `makeHttpRequest` 7 times with a 1 second delay in between each call? - I've tried `setTimeout` and delay but can't seem to work out the correct way of using them.

```
var post_data = that.createIRRC("AAAAAQAAAAEAAAB1Aw==");
that.makeHttpRequest(onError, onSucces, "", post_data, false)
```

Comment: Show us the attempt with the `setTimeout`, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pause one second after the http request completes before starting the next one, then you can use `setTimeout()` in the completion callback.

And, since it now looks like you want to send a sequence of codes, you can pass in the sequence of codes you want to send in an array and this will call `that.createIRRC()` for each successive code:

```
function sendSequence(cntr, data, delay) {
    // create post_data for next code to send in the sequence
    let post_data = that.createIRRC(data[cntr]);
    that.makeHttpRequest(onError, function() {
        // if we haven't done this limit times yet, then set a timer and
        // run it again after one second
        if (++cntr < data.length) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                sendSequence(cntr, data, delay);
            }, delay);
        } else {
            onSuccess();
        }
    }, "", post_data,false);
}

// define the codes
// this should probably be done once at a higher level where you can define
// all the codes you might want to send so you can reference them by a meaningful
// name rather than an obscure string
let codes = {
    right: "AAAAAQAAAAEAAAAzAw==",
    down: "AAAAAQAAAAEAAABlAw==",
    select: "AAAAAQAAAAEAAABlAw==",
    options: "AAAAAgAAAJcAAAA2Aw==",
    hdmi2: "AAAAAgAAABoAAABbAw==",
    hdmi3: "AAAAAgAAABoAAABcAw=="
}

// create sequence of codes to be sent
let dataSequence = [
   codes.hdmi2, codes.options,
   codes.down, codes.down, codes.down, codes.down, codes.down, codes.down, codes.down,
   codes.right, 
   codes.down, codes.down, codes.down, codes.down,
   codes.select, codes.hdmi3
 ];
// start the process with initial cnt of 0 and 
// send the sequence of data to be sent and 
// with a one second delay between commands
sendSequence(0, dataSequence, 1000);
```

Comment: Note that here `onError` and `onSuccess` will be called multiple times

Comment: @arboreal84 - No, `onError` would only ever get called once.  The loop stops after onError is called - this was designed that way on purpose.  `onSuccess` would get called multiple times as that appears to be what the OP wants, otherwise the OP had no way to get access to the response from each call.

Comment: Where do I put the createIRRC line in this? - I've been trying both this code and that by @arboreal84 and I can't get either to work :( - I'm trying to send a sequence of codes (Option / Down x 6 / Right / Down / Select / HDMI3) to a TV to select a particular function (no discreet code available). If I use multiple "that.makeHttpRequest(onError, onSucces, "", post_data,false);" lines it works *sometimes*, others it gets confused.

Comment: here's the code for reference: https://pastebin.com/h3wHkCxj - Case 5 is where I'm trying to send the above sequence.

Comment: @Jason - You have not described what you're trying to do with `that.createIRRC()` inside the loop.  Do you just do it once and use the same value for every cycle of the loop?  Or are you trying to pass a different parameter to that function for each cycle of the loop?  The code in your question just shows you passing a constant to that so I assumed you could just do that once before the loop and then reference the same variable every time.  If the requirement is different than that, then please show multiple calls and what you're passing each time.  Your question is unclear in this regard.

Comment: @Jason - OK, I see now in the pastebin there are different codes.  Working on an example for you.  That was not illustrated in your question at all.

Comment: @jfriend00 I need to send multiple commands to a TV. The loop in question is for 7 "down" presses with the same post_data. Additionally I need to send other commands with different codes in post_data. See pastebin link above for more info.

Comment: @Jason - OK, I've modified my answer so that `run()` (now renamed to `sendSequence()`) takes an initial count and a sequence of commands to be sent and it sends each of those commands one after another with a delay between them.  I don't quite understand how you're using `onSuccess` (I spelled it with two `s` at the end).  It is called after each command succeeds.  It was not clear what your code wanted to do with that.  This code could be changed to only call that or something else at the end of the whole sequence.

Comment: @jfriend00 i didn't write that code, calling at the end of the sequence sounds more sensible if possible!?

Comment: @Jason - OK, modified one last time to call `onSuccess()` only when it is done with the whole sequence.

Answer (score 0):

```
var times = 0;

var ivl = setInterval(function () {
    var post_data = that.createIRRC("AAAAAQAAAAEAAAB1Aw==");
    that.makeHttpRequest(onError, onSucces, "", post_data, false)

    if (++times === 7) {
        clearInterval(ivl);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: @Jason - Note, this answer starts a new request each second.  It does not wait 1 second after the previous request finished (so it depends if that's exactly what you wanted or not - if a response gets slow, you could be launching more than one request at a time here and responses could even come out of order though that is unlikely).  It also does not abort if there's an error, it just keeps going.